# How to store separately the repeated values inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, duplicates

I have this array of objects in Javascript:

```
var arrayData = [
            { id: "0", x: -1, y: 38},
            { id: "1", x: -2.7823, y: 43.444},
            { id: "2", x: -1.1654, y: 38.12088},
            { id: "3", x: -1, y: 38},
            { id: "4", x: -2.7823, y: 43.444 },
            { id: "5", x: -1.1654, y: 38.12088},
            { id: "6", x: -1.1654, y: 38.12088},
            
        ]
```

and i'd need to check what objects have the same property x and y and someway store this objects separately so i can access later to them.
i've got this:

```
var copy = arrayData.slice(0);
// first loop goes over every element
               for (var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i ++) {  
                    
                   // loop over every element in the copy and see if it's the same
                   for (var w = i + 1; w < copy.length; w++) {
                       if ((arrayFotos[i].x === copy[w].x) && (arrayFotos[i].y === copy[w].y)) {                               
                           
                           if(!duplicates.includes(arrayFotos[i].id))
                               duplicates.push(arrayFotos[i].id);
                           if(!duplicates.includes(copy[w].id))
                               duplicates.push(copy[w].id);
                       }                          
                                           
                   }
```

This returns me an array with all ids of the objects which
have repeated x and y properties but i need a way to store
them separately so i have: [0,3][1,4][2,5,6]. Is there any
way to do it? Thanks if u want to help me.

Comment: And where is the problem? Isn't it working or is it droping an error?

Comment: Could you edit this question and move the part "This returns me an array with all..." out of the code block? It's hard to read because you have to scroll the code area so other users may not see what you are after. I would edit it myself but I'm getting an error when I try...

Comment: @Jon The problem was i didnt know how to get the repeated objects id grouped. I had them all in the same array. The answer from Nina solved it.

Comment: @Totò Done! Im so newbie. I will try to make sure all the comments are out of the code snipets in the future.Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a hash table and collect `id` for same coordinates.

```js
var arrayData = [{ id: "0", x: -1, y: 38 }, { id: "1", x: -2.7823, y: 43.444 },  { id: "2", x: -1.1654, y: 38.12088 }, { id: "3", x: -1, y: 38 }, { id: "4", x: -2.7823, y: 43.444 }, { id: "5", x: -1.1654, y: 38.12088 }, { id: "6", x: -1.1654, y: 38.12088 }],
    duplicates
    hashtable = {};

for (var i = 0; i < arrayData.length; i++) {  
    let key = ['x', 'y'].map(k => arrayData[i][k]).join('|');
    hashtable[key] = hashtable[key] || [];
    hashtable[key].push(arrayData[i].id);
}

duplicates = Object.values(hashtable);

console.log(duplicates);
```